# Installing Pygame - 32-bit vs 64-bit

Tags: python, pygame, 32bit-64bit

I tried to download Pygame onto my computer. I accidentally downloaded the 64-bit version when I have a Python 3.5 32-bit version on my computer. I am using the Windows command prompt python pip installation module. I realized my mistake and disinstalled it, saved the 32-bit version onto the computer, and tried to use the command prompt again. When an error came up, I specified the specific path of the Pygame 32-bit version but this came up:

```
   pygame-1.9.3-cp35-cp35m.win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

When I use the python -m pip install Pygame, it installs the 64-bit version, even though I deleted all copies of it from the computer, even in the Downloads file. Is there any way around this? I want to install the 32-vit version.

Comment: If you enter `python -m pip install pygame` it will download the correct pygame version from PyPI and install it. Do you have more than one Python version installed? I always recommend to use the Python launcher and enter the specific version on Windows: `py -3.5 -m pip install pygame`. Also, are you sure you have a 32 bit Python version?

Comment: @skrx I tried your command, but it downloaded the 64-bit version again. I know I have a 32-bit version of python. When I install pygame, I see the file name of the 64-bit version come up. Aslo, when I try to import it on the IDLE, it states that there is no module named pygame.

Comment: Please post the text (the version, bitness, etc.) that appears when you start IDLE and when you enter `python` in the command-line. Do you have more than one Python version installed?

Comment: @skrx This is what the IDLE prints when I open it.

Comment: @skrx  "Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information."

Comment: Ahhh...that's what I did. I installed the 64-bit version Anaconda python module and it confused the computer into thinking the Python version was 64-bit. I disinstalled Anaconda and tried the command again. This time, the installation worked.

Comment: Thank you! I found out the error after typing in python in the command shell. I confused the 32 and 64-bit versions because, in school, I use the 64-bit Python version, but at home, I use the 32-bit one. So sometimes I get the two mixed up.

Comment: Great that you've figured it out. Have fun with pygame.

Comment: I've posted a short summary if someone finds this in the future. Is there anything to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that two Python versions were installed, one 32 bit and one 64 bit ( installed with Anaconda). The Anaconda version took precedence over the normal 32 bit version in the command-line, so it tried to install pygame for the wrong version. We figured that out by looking at the start text (with the version numbers, bitness, etc.) that appears when you start Python from the command-line and in IDLE.